# How to query two same values in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have table in SQL Server 2008 with following fields

```
RoomUserId->Primary key
RoomId->Foreign Key of Table Rooms
UserId->Foreign Key of Table Users
```

Now I have the values as following where the `RoomId` is common for both users

```
   RoomUserId  RoomId UserId
         1      11    1
         2      11    2
         3      12    1
         4      12    3
         5      13    1
         6      13    4
```

Now I need a SQL query to find the `roomid` of two users which is distinct. i.e, `roomid` of user 1 and user 2, `roomid` of user 1 and user 3.

Please anyone help me with is since I am new to SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT r1.roomId FROM room r1 JOIN room r2 ON r1.roomId = r2.roomId WHERE r1.userId = 1 AND r2.userId = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean find a roomid that is common to users:

```
select distinct f.roomid  
from rooms f  
inner join rooms s on f.roomid = s.roomid and f.userid <> s.userid
```

Or you can use grouping:

```
select roomid  
from rooms  
group by roomid  
having count(distinct userid) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only ever need rooms where there is more than one user then this will work:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT RoomID
FROM    RoomUser r1
        INNER JOIN RoomUser r2
            ON r1.RoomID = r2.RoomID
            AND r1.RoomUserID != r2.RoomUserID
```

If you need the room ID of rooms with x users then use the `Having` Clause, this is more extensible than self joining e.g. if you need to find room IDs with 3 or more User IDs then you would end up with:

```
SELECT  RoomID
FROM    RoomUser
GROUP BY RoomID
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT UserID) > 3
```

Whereas using self joins, while probably more efficient will end up with some quite messy SQL. Check execution plans and run some tests to see which is more efficient for your needs.

If you actually need the user IDs of the Users in Rooms with more than one User ID then you could use a CTE to build a comma separated string of users in each room:

```
;WITH RoomUserCTE AS
(   SELECT  RoomID, 
            MIN(UserID) [UserID], 
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), MIN(UserID)) [Users], 
            0 [Recursion]
    FROM    RoomUser
    GROUP BY RoomID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  a.RoomID, 
            b.UserID [UserID], 
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), Users + ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, b.UserID)), 
            Recursion + 1
    FROM    RoomUserCTE a
            INNER JOIN RoomUser b
                ON a.RoomID = b.RoomID
                AND b.UserID > a.UserID
)
SELECT  RoomID, Users
FROM    (   SELECT  *, MAX(Recursion) OVER(PARTITION BY RoomID) [MaxRecursion]
            FROM    RoomUserCTE
        ) cte
WHERE   MaxRecursion = Recursion
```

For the data in your question this will yield

```
| RoomID  |  Users  |
|---------+---------|
|  11     |  1, 2   |
|  12     |  1, 3   |
|  13     |  1, 4   |
```

This would work no matter how many user IDs were associated with the same Room ID, so again is more forward compatible.